# get java installation path using shell script in rhel

Tags: java, shell, rpm, rhel

I have to automate a process in which i need to install java on RHEL 7, using rpm package and then update the security jars later on the installed location. Once i execute the java rpm, how would i get the correct installed path?  when i execute `which java` it says `/bin/java`.  However, i need the installation location using shell script.
Here, the actual installation happened at `/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_55/jre`. I want to get this location. Can some one suggest me how to retrieve this?

Comment: If installed correctly the environment variable $JAVA_HOME should have been set.

Comment: Hi..java installed successfully, however no env variable was set. I have to set manually that also...(java -version is showing the results)

Answer (score 2):

The [`readlink`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink) program (part of [*coreutils*](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html), and available on any RHEL version) can resolve symbolic links:

```
foo=$(readlink -f $(which java))
echo $foo
```

(You may also have [`realpath`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/realpath), but perhaps not).

Answer (score 0):

Java RPM packages from Oracle support the 'alternatives' system, which provides the detail you are seeking.  For example, after installing a recent JRE, 'alternatives' reports like so:

```
[user@host ~]$ alternatives --display java
java - status is auto.
 link currently points to /usr/java/jre1.8.0_60/bin/java
etc...
```

The output is relatively friendly for scripting.